# How to properly parse JSON in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am not sure how to properly parse through nested JSON using Groovy.  I have included a working Python script so you can see exactly what I'm trying to do in Groovy.

JSON I need to parse:

```
json_payload = {"number": 3585, "url": "https://jenkins.test.com/job/test/3585/",
                  "displayName": "test_3585", "timestamp": 1516992464686,
                  "actions": [{"causes": [{"userId": "test"}]}]}
```

What I want to do (Python):

```
class JenkinsParser:
    def __init__(self, json_data):

        self.display_name = json_data['displayName']
        self.url = json_data['url']
        self.start_time = json_data['timestamp']
        self.exec_url = json_data['url']
        self.exec_number = json_data['number']
        self.user = None
        actions = json_data['actions']
        for a in actions:
            if 'causes' in a:
                for cause in a['causes']:
                    if 'userId' in cause:
                        self.user = cause['userId']

        url_split = self.execution_url.split("/job/")
        self.jenkins_url = url_split[0]
        self.job_name = url_split[-1].split("/")[0]
```

Note:  The Groovy does not necessarily need to be a class, and doesn't need to use JSonSlurper

If I use JsonSlurper

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(json_payload)
```

Can I access all the values I need like so?

```
result.displayName
result.url
result.timestamp
result.url
result.number
result.actions.causes.userId
```

I'm not sure how to grab userId..

Comment: NOTE:  There will always be actions and causes and there will be more than one element for both of these keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the values like you described.

You could access userId like `result​.actions.first().causes.first().userId​` if you're sure your data is structured exactly like that.  If you may or may not have actions, or may or may not have causes, you could do something like `result​.actions?.first()?.causes?.first()?.userId​` to make your access null-safe, or you could use the spread (`*.`) operator to access userId if there may be multiple actions or causes.

Per your comment about something returning null, this works as expected:

```
def json_payload = """{"number": 3585, "url": "https://jenkins.test.com/job/test/3585/", "displayName": "test_3585", "timestamp": 1516992464686, "actions": [{"causes": [{"userId": "test"}]}]}"""
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(json_payload)
return result​.actions?.first()?.causes?.first()?.userId​
```

and returns "test".  If you are not seeing similar results you may have a syntax error or different key in your actual data.

Comment: result​.actions.first().causes.first().userId​ returned null for some reason

Comment: there will always be action and causes - and there will always be more than one element within action and more than one element within causes.  What should I do ?

Comment: You have to figure out what you need your result to be.  If you want all of the user IDs, you can use a spread operator.  If you only want the first, or the last, you can use .first() or .last().  You can also look into .find and .findAll to perform logic based on what is present.  There are a lot of options, but there is no "right" answer without knowing more about what you actually need to do.

Comment: userId will always have one value

Comment: but actions and causes will have multiple items, if that makes sense

Comment: This solution does not seem to be working - I will make a new post with more specific question.