# Do I need a for loop in order to find a key/value in json using Groovy JsonSlurper?

Tags: json, groovy

python for loop:

```
actions = json_data['actions']
for a in actions:
    if 'causes' in a:
        for cause in a['causes']:
            if 'userId' in cause:
                self.user = cause['userId']
```

How do I do this in groovy?

```
def jenkins_data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(obj)
```

Using this json, I'm not sure how to drill down to grab userId.  I imagine I need to use a for loop to check for each element in the list for the 'cause' key and then repeat for the 'userId' key.

Here is an example payload I'm dealing with.

```
self.payload_a = {"number": 3585, "url": "https://test.m.test.com/job/gfdsgdsf/3585/",
                  "displayName": "master_3585", "timestamp": 1516992464686,
                  "actions": [{"something": "nothing"}, {"causes": [{"userId": "build"}]}]}
```

Using an example payload I am able to to echo jenkins_data.actions.causes and see output
however echoing jenkins_data.actions.causes.userId is null (even though the userId is definitely in the payload)

When I run

```
echo jenkins_data.actions.causes
```

I get

```
[null, [[_TestIdCause, shortDescription:Started by user, B, userId:valueweneed, userName:test, B]], null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly parse JSON in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278365/how-to-properly-parse-json-in-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes . You need to put a loop to traverse all nodes in json.

Parsing json is quire complex.

According to Json : Any data type can be returned from a same node like ('userId') while traversing. like shown below

```
"userId" : "A"
...
"userId" : { ... }
...
"userId" : [ ... ]
```

You need to handle this return data as per you wish. As you ask in the question to get the `userId` node, just use the xpath like shown below

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsontxt)

println json.actions.causes.userId
```

In your case it returns list. so just `flatten` it.

```
println json.actions.causes.userId.flatten()
```